# How to expose multi-element field in base class to derived classes

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, c#-3.0

I have a base class that declares a grouping of objects.  That grouping can be an array, List, Collection, that's up to me.

The derived classes of this base class are the ones that actually set the values of this multi-element field.  What is the best way to expose this field to the derived classes?

Comment: Could you say more about this field?

Comment: This field is a fixed-length collection but the elements need to be mutable to the derived classes.  In this case I think the natural choice is an array as the type of field.  It might be better explained as the base class will allocate and the derived class will assign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expose it via a *protected minimal interface*:

```
class Base {
    private List<string> _elems = new List<string>();
    protected ICollection<string> ElementStore { get { return _elems; } }
}

class Derived : Base {
    public Derived() {
        ElementStore.Add("Foo");
        ElementStore.Add("Bar");
    }
}
```